# Sort items in UltimateListCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to create an ultimate list ctrl based table where the user can sort the columns by clicking on the column header. Here's the code I attempted:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.mixins.listctrl as listmix
from wx.lib.agw import ultimatelistctrl as ULC

APPNAME='Sortable Ultimate List Ctrl'
APPVERSION='1.0'
MAIN_WIDTH=300
MAIN_HEIGHT=300

musicdata = {
0 : ("Bad English", "The Price Of Love"),
1 : ("DNA featuring Suzanne Vega", "Tom's Diner"),
2 : ("George Michael", "Praying For Time"),
3 : ("Gloria Estefan", "Here We Are"),
4 : ("Linda Ronstadt", "Don't Know Much"),
5 : ("Michael Bolton", "How Am I Supposed To Live Without You"),
6 : ("Paul Young", "Oh Girl"),
}

########################################################################
class TestUltimateListCtrlPanel(wx.Panel, listmix.ColumnSorterMixin):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS, size=(MAIN_WIDTH,MAIN_HEIGHT))

        self.index = 0

        self.list_ctrl = ULC.UltimateListCtrl(self, -1, agwStyle=ULC.ULC_REPORT|ULC.ULC_HAS_VARIABLE_ROW_HEIGHT)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, "Artist")
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, "Title", wx.LIST_FORMAT_RIGHT)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, "Download")

        items = musicdata.items()
        index = 0
        for key, data in items:
            pos=self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(index, data[0])
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 1, data[1])
            #self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 2, data[2])
            button = wx.Button(self.list_ctrl, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Download")
                self.list_ctrl.SetItemWindow(pos, col=2, wnd=button, expand=True)
            self.list_ctrl.SetItemData(index, key)
            index += 1

        # Now that the list exists we can init the other base class,
        # see wx/lib/mixins/listctrl.py
        self.itemDataMap = musicdata
        listmix.ColumnSorterMixin.__init__(self, 3)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_COL_CLICK, self.OnColClick, self.list_ctrl)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


    def GetListCtrl(self):
        return self.list_ctrl

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnColClick(self, event):
        pass

########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,wx.ID_ANY,'%s v%s' % (APPNAME,APPVERSION),size=(MAIN_WIDTH,MAIN_HEIGHT),style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.CLIP_CHILDREN)

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = TestUltimateListCtrlPanel(self)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()[/CODE]
```

Clicking on the column does not sort the 'Artist' or 'Title' fields. I want to be able to sort them when the user clicks on the column headers. Please help.

This is how it looks like

[image: Sortable Ultimate List Ctrl]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be bug in the UltimateListControl implementation. It does not refresh itself after column is clicked. This works for me:

```
DATA = {
0 : ("3", "3", "1"),
1 : ("2", "1", "2"),
2 : ("1", "2", "3")
}

import wx
import wx.lib.mixins.listctrl as listmix
from wx.lib.agw import ultimatelistctrl as ULC

class MyList(ULC.UltimateListCtrl, listmix.ColumnSorterMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent, columns):
        ULC.UltimateListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, agwStyle=ULC.ULC_REPORT | ULC.ULC_HAS_VARIABLE_ROW_HEIGHT)
        self.itemDataMap = DATA
        listmix.ColumnSorterMixin.__init__(self, columns)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_COL_CLICK, self.OnColumn)

    def OnColumn(self, e):
        self.Refresh()
        e.Skip()

    def GetListCtrl(self):
        return self

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.list = MyList(self, 3)
        self.list.InsertColumn(0, "A")
        self.list.InsertColumn(1, "B")
        self.list.InsertColumn(2, "C")

        items = DATA.items()
        for key, data in items:
            index = self.list.Append(data)
            self.list.SetItemData(index, key)

        self.Show()

app = wx.App(False)
win = MainWindow(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

Just for reference, it works as expected with normal ListCtrl:

```
DATA = {
0 : ("3", "3", "1"),
1 : ("2", "1", "2"),
2 : ("1", "2", "3")
}

import wx
import wx.lib.mixins.listctrl as listmix

class MyList(wx.ListCtrl, listmix.ColumnSorterMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent, columns):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        self.itemDataMap = DATA
        listmix.ColumnSorterMixin.__init__(self, columns)

    def GetListCtrl(self):
        return self

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.list = MyList(self, 3)
        self.list.InsertColumn(0, "A")
        self.list.InsertColumn(1, "B")
        self.list.InsertColumn(2, "C")

        items = DATA.items()
        for key, data in items:
            index = self.list.Append(data)
            self.list.SetItemData(index, key)

        self.Show()

app = wx.App(False)
win = MainWindow(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

It may be fixed in a newer versions of wxPython: http://trac.wxwidgets.org/changeset/68347

Comment: your code is a very good alternative. my code works in wxpython 2.9.2 development version. may be it's a bug in wxpython 2.8 which was fixed  in the later versions.

Comment: It seems to be fixed around August. The latest 2.8 stable is older.